# how to assign value from table using select into statement inside a loop?

Tags: plsql

I am trying to check whether a empid exists in an employee table and throw a custom exception.
I noticed that select into statement does not work inside a loop.
If I get rid of the loop and check for employee id 1, the following code works.

```
  --while(rownox <= countx)
    --LOOP
        SELECT * INTO emp FROM employee1 WHERE rownum = rownox; (line no 18)
        IF(emp.empid = testx)
            THEN flagx := rownox;
        END IF;
        --rownox := rownox + 1;
    --END LOOP;
```

I get the error
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 18
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
for r in (
    select * from employee1
)
loop
    if r.empid = testx then
        flagx := rownox;
    end if;
end loop;
```

This fetches each row from employee1 into a record named `r` which is implicitly declared as part of the loop.

`where rownum = n` will never work for n > 1 because rownum is only incremented for each row returned from a query.

Notice that PL/SQL, like SQL, has no brackets around conditions.

Comment: You can use brackets if you have complex condition and they do their job.

Comment: I mean the syntax is `if expression then`, not `if (expression) then`. Some other languages use `if (expression)` because they have no `then` keyword.

Comment: and why not `if (expression) then` ?

Comment: Why not `if (((((expression))))) then`? Why not `select (((((sysdate))))) from dual`? There are a lot of places we can add redundant syntax elements. The syntax of the language does not call for brackets around expressions, because they are already terminated by the `then` keyword.